# Dynamic Graph Data Structure

Tags: java, spring, data-structures, graph, shortest-path

So I have an e-commerce app and would like to add a recommendation feature. It's a simple one. If you buy item a then the system will look at what other items did item a buyer's also buy.

I think this can be applied using graphs and all pairs shortest path algorithm, but how do you make this dynamic. If I add / remove a product or the proximity / similarity of products changes how do you limit the scope of your change? How to avoid re-calculating the shortest path for the entire graph?